# Git - Diff between branches in old commits

Tags: git, branch, diff, git-commit, git-diff

I have this:

```
branch: commit 1, commit 2, 3,4
master: commit 1, commit 2, 3,4,5,6,7
```

How can you make a diff between branch after `commit 2` (in that point of history) and master in `commit 3`?

Comment: [phd's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44400650/1256452) is correct (and upvoted), but note that the trick is to realize that "branch" in Git really means very little. Git is all about *commits;* a branch name is just a way to identify one specific commit, with the extra feature that every time you add commits to the branch, the name-to-commit-ID mapping *automatically* moves so that the name translates into the latest commit. The branch is therefore not really the *name* but rather the set of commits found *from* the name.

Answer (score 6):

Let's name your commits b1, b2, b3, b4; m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7. To diff two commits you can run `git diff commit1 commit2`. In your case it's `git diff b2 m3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can always and in any time check the difference between commits with

```
git diff commit1..commit2
```

You can substitute commit with branch names.

```
git diff master..foo
```

or also with HEAD

```
git diff master..HEAD
```

and so on.

Here a real example:

```
git diff e8e1956c174da9d..90f2b3ee988d8b6
```

Note that the complete hash is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

The detailed answer could be:

First checkout branch: git checkout branch

Then run: git log

Get the SHA/commit-id of the commit you want and copy it. (I am calling it SHA1)

Then go back to the master branch: git checkout master

Then run: git log

Get the SHA/commit-id of the commit you want and copy it. (I am calling it SHA2)

Then while staying on Master, you can run: git diff SHA1 SHA2